# Existence of periodic solutions to scalar Riccati equations

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Consider the periodic Riccati equation $y'(x)=y(x)^2+q(x)$ on the real line $\mathbb{R}$, where $q\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is a periodic function with period $T=1$. Suppose $q(x)$ can take both positive and negative values but $\int_0^1 q(x)dx<0$. Does a periodic solution to this Riccati equation exist? Any references? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is quite similar to a boundary value problem. You have a periodic solution (of period $1$) if and only if $y(1)=y(0)$, and that could certainly happen (and whether or not it does depends on $q$), for example for $q=-1$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, you are right. If q<0, then there are results guaranteeing the existence of solutions. Here I am concerned with the case above (q(x) can take positive and negative values). It seems that there is no good criterion for that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is negative.
The MSN review says that this is the contents of

MR1466035
Tang, Fenjun
The periodic solutions of Riccati equation with periodic coefficients.
Ann. Differential Equations 13 (1997), no. 2, 165–169.

I looked at this paper and the argument there makes no sense.

Setting $y=-w'/w$ we obtain $w''+qw=0$, and periodicity
of $y$ means $w(x+T)=\lambda w(x)$ for some $\lambda\neq 0$, so that $w$ is an eigenfunction of the shift operator. For generic $q$ there will be two such eigenfunctions (with distinct eigenvalues), and the question is whether at least one of them is free of zeros on $[0,T]$.

Here is a simple counterexample. Let $T=2\pi$, and
$q(x)=1$ for $0\leq x\leq 3\pi/2$, and then extend $q$ to a smooth
$2\pi$ periodic function arbitrarily, but so that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}q(x)dx<0.$$
Then the general solution $w$ of our linear equation will
be of the form $w(x)=A\cos(x-\alpha),\; 0<x<3\pi/2$, so every solution
has at least one zero. This means that the corresponding Riccati equation has no smooth real solutions $y=-w'/w$ defined on the real line, thus no
periodic solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I noticed Fenjun Tang's this paper, and I have his paper at hand. But I cannot follow his argument and I am not sure his result is right or not. So I turn to here for help. Anyone interested in Fenjun Tang's paper can email me to ask for a copy of his paper by changwei.xiong@scu.edu.cn

Comment: I suppose you are asking about a REAL periodic solution?

Comment: Yes, a real periodic solution.